# Geode Client/Server operation - keep the data serialized

Tags: serialization, geode

According to geode documentation, partitioned data is always kept serialized ( this I believe is sent from client to server in serialized form ):

To minimize the cost of serialization and deserialization, Geode avoids changing the data format whenever possible. This means your data might be stored in the cache in serialized or deserialized form, depending on how you use it. For example, if a server acts only as a storage location for data distribution between clients, it makes sense to leave the data in serialized form, ready to be transmitted to clients that request it. Partitioned region data is always initially stored in serialized form.

However, on practice when the non simple key is used in testing for put operation on, the following error is received: Serialization filter is rejecting class

Does this means that the data is stored as non serializable on server, or its just validation error ( which may be removed by setting SERIALIZABLE_OBJECT_FILTER )?

BR

Yulian Oifa

Answer (score 0):

Values are stored in serialized form by default. But keys are deserialized as soon as they get to the server. You can set the SERIALIZABLE_OBJECT_FILTER if you want to use a java serializable key.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the answer.
Is there any way to make geode storing the keys also in serializable form? Or only custom serialization prior to putting the object into cache would be required?